# Can't get checkboxes to show in php from form get

Tags: php, reactjs, post, checkbox, get

```js
'use strict';

const e = React.createElement;

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
    this.state={checked: false}

  //this.handleCheckedChange = this.handleCheckedChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  this.formContent = this.display1();
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Your information is: ' + JSON.stringify(this.formContent) + " " + "Please Make Sure To Select From One of The Vacation Options and Activities From Below");
  
    event.preventDefault();}

  

  NumberList1(props) {
    let listItems = React.createElement("p", {key: props.id}, props.item.text, React.createElement("input", {
      type: "checkbox",
      value: "1",
      onChange: () => this.setState({checked: true}),
      defaultChecked: false
    }))
    
    return (
      listItems      
    )
  }

  display1(){
      
    let props = [{id: 0, text: "City Tours", completed: false}, 
    {id: 1, text: "Sports", completed: false}, 
    {id: 2, text: "Cycling", completed: false}, 
    {id: 3, text: "Museums", completed: false}, 
    {id: 4, text: "Boating", completed: false}];  
    let listItems = props.map((item) => this.NumberList1({
      key: props.id, 
      item: item})); 

      return(React.createElement("div", {}, listItems));
  }
        

  render() {
   

    //if(this.state.liked == true){
    
      //;}
    
    
      //'button',{ onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },"New Zealand",

    return (React.createElement("form", {onSubmit: this.handleSubmit, action: 'http://localhost/test.php', method: "get",
    className: "todo-list"
  },"Select Activities From Below", (this.formContent),React.createElement("br", {}), 
  React.createElement("input", {type:"submit", value: "Submit"}), 
  React.createElement("input", {type:"reset", value: "Reset"})))
}

}

 const domContainer = document.getElementById("new");

 ReactDOM.render(
   (e(LikeButton)),
   domContainer);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8" name = "viewport" content="width= device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
               
        <meta name="travel">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylecontact.css">
        <title> Mega Travel</title>      
    </head>
    
    
    <nav class="one">
        <img class="logo" src="images/mega travel logo.png" alt="Mega Travel Logo" style="width:20%"/>
        <hr style="border: 12px solid lightgray;" />


    </nav>
    <nav class="two">
       
        <a class="home" href="#" >Home &nbsp;&nbsp;</a> 
        <a class="about" href="#" > About Us &nbsp;&nbsp; </a>        
        <a class="agent" href="#"> Contact Agent </a>
        
    </nav>   

    <body>
        <!-- Load React. -->
        <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.js"></script>-->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>    
        <!-- Load our React component. -->  
      
           
            <div id= "formfind" style="width: max-content;">
                <script src="../src/FormFind.js"></script>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Please Check Our Activities For Each Destination:</th>
                    </table>
                    <div>
                        
                        <span id="new">
                            <script src="../src/NewZealand.js"></script>                         
                        </span>     
                      
                        </div>
                                       
                
            </div>     
        
                
           
        
      
    
          
    
      
    </body>

</html>
```

I am trying to show what users checked from a list of activities on my /test.php page.  However, I keep only getting Array () 1 to show.  I can get another page which inputs texts to show properly but I think I am missing something important with the checkboxes but I can't seem to pinpoint what that is.  Any help would be apprecaited

```
const e = React.createElement;

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
    this.state={checked: false}

  //this.handleCheckedChange = this.handleCheckedChange.bind(this);
  //this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  this.formContent = this.display1();
  }



  NumberList1(props) {
    let listItems = React.createElement("p", {key: props.id}, props.item.text, React.createElement("input", {
      type: "checkbox",
      value: "1",
      onChange: () => this.setState({checked: true}),
      defaultChecked: false
    }))

    return (
      listItems      
    )
  }

  display1(){

    let props = [{id: 0, text: "City Tours", completed: false}, 
    {id: 1, text: "Sports", completed: false}, 
    {id: 2, text: "Cycling", completed: false}, 
    {id: 3, text: "Museums", completed: false}, 
    {id: 4, text: "Boating", completed: false}];  
    let listItems = props.map((item) => this.NumberList1({
      key: props.id, 
      item: item})); 

      return(React.createElement("div", {}, listItems));
  }


  render() {


    //if(this.state.liked == true){

      //;}


      //'button',{ onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },"New Zealand",

    return (React.createElement("form", {action: 'http://localhost/test.php', method: "get",
    className: "todo-list"
  },"Select Activities From Below", (this.formContent),React.createElement("br", {}), 
  React.createElement("input", {type:"submit", value: "Submit"}), 
  React.createElement("input", {type:"reset", value: "Reset"})))
}

}

 const domContainer = document.getElementById("new");

 ReactDOM.render(
   (e(LikeButton)),
   domContainer);
```

This is test.php code

```
<head> 
</head>
<body>
<?php 
    echo print_r($_GET); 
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is html

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8" name = "viewport" content="width= device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

        <meta name="travel">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylecontact.css">
        <title> Mega Travel</title>      
    </head>


    <body>
        <!-- Load React. -->
        <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.js"></script>-->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>    
        <!-- Load our React component. -->  

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Please Check Our Activities For Each Destination:</th>
                    </table>
                    <div>

                        <span id="new">
                            <script src="../src/NewZealand.js"></script>                         
                        </span>                        


            </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: "keep only getting Array () 1 to show"  Where exactly is it that you are seeing that?  What page is the page that you are showing above?  Your question mentions "confirm.php", but the code seems to be posting to "test.php".  If PHP is relevant to this question (and I imaging it is), then you should include the PHP code in the question too.  If it happens to _not_ be relevant, then you should remove the `php` tag from the question.

Comment: Yes, sorry that is a type-o it is test.php

Comment: @Patrick As I stated in my question.  I could/can get other text form to display properly when using that php code...therefore it would seem the problem isn't the php code.

Comment: Can you show the rendered HTML created by the react code?

Comment: Yes, it shows as it should.  5 checkboxes one on top of another with the correct text beside each one.

Comment: Mean could you please include that HTML in your question.

Comment: It's the HTML created by the react code that I'm interested in, not your base HTML.

Comment: I don't understand what you want.  The react code which creates the html is already in the question.  It was the first code I posted.

Comment: "the HTML _created by_ the react code "  I'm not really sure how else to put it.  The HTML of the form that you're trying to submit.  The HTML that shows "5 checkboxes one on top of another with the correct text beside each one"